# Configuring Doom Emacs to autocomplete code within a header file

Tags: doom, cc-mode, company, irony-mode

I am pretty new to Doom emacs and am so far loving it. However, I am having trouble autocompleting code when from an external include file.

I have the following code

[image]

and am having trouble autocompleting anything after `Eigen::`

I would like to, on the fly, run a command that tells company-irony to parse where I installed the Eigen file, so that it will autocomplete everything in that namespace. How do I do this?